# Bash - installing Ocaml-top

Tags: bash, terminal, path, ocaml, opam

I am trying to install Ocaml-Top IDE from command line. I have already installed Ocaml and OPAM using Homebrew (brew install opam, brew install ocaml), but when I enter:

```
opam install ocaml-top
```

I get

```
[ERROR] No OPAM root found at /Users/student/.opam.
```

Do I need to add this to my PATH?

UPDATE: Suggestion helped, but there is an issue with the package name: I get

```
[ERROR] No package named ocaml-top found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have missed the following caveat, notably `opam init`, when you ran `brew install opam`:

```
$ brew info opam
...
==> Caveats
OPAM uses ~/.opam by default for its package database, so you need to
initialize it first by running (as a normal user):

$  opam init

Run the following to initialize your environment variables:

$  eval `opam config env`

To export the needed variables every time, add them to your dotfiles.
  * On Bash, add them to `~/.bash_profile`.
  * On Zsh, add them to `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc` instead.

Documentation and tutorials are available at https://opam.ocaml.org, or
via "man opam" and "opam --help".

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I get: [ERROR] No package named ocaml-top found. Does the package have a different registered name? Got this instructing from typerex.com